# Delete Row If Cell Contains Text After Second Hyphen

Tags: vba, excel, find

I have a long column of strings, example:

```
GREENCAT-01-AB-01
BLUEDOG-800-CC-1
BLUECAT-1
GREENDOG-804
BLACKSHEEP-58
PINKMOUSE-900-AB
```

Desired Result:

```
BLUECAT-1
GREENDOG-804
BLACKSHEEP-58
```

I am trying to use the Find function to find any string that have a second hyphen and delete that row. I was using "wild cards" but they need to be specific and some strings have only 1 or 2 numbers after the first hyphen while others have 3 or 4.

Help?

```
Set SrchRng = WS.Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
    Do
    Set c = SrchRng.Find(What:="-***-", LookAt:=xlPart)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Delete
    Loop While Not c Is Nothing
```

Comment: For future reference, an asterisk wild card matches any number of characters, where as a question mark matches only one character. This means when using the asterisk you don't need to worry about about how many characters there might be :)

Answer (score 2):

simply add a "*" both at the beginning and at the end of your "What" parameter

```
Set SrchRng = ws.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
Do
    Set c = SrchRng.Find(What:="*-*-*", LookAt:=xlPart)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Delete
Loop While Not c Is Nothing
```

Comment: I read that those were all in the same cell.  Good job reading the entire question.

Comment: agreed. Attention to detail. +1

Comment: thanks @ScottCraner, actually that OP wasn't that "immediate"

Comment: @TrackStar2016: did you get through it?